# How can I extract every string between two words from text using grep and save it into a new file?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a 2.2 GB .log file from which I want to extract only a specific line of text between two words and save it into another file using the Terminal with regex on my Mac. This line appears a lot of times in the file each with a different timestamp. But I can't figure out what the command is to do exactly that. I would like to extract every single string that appears between "Timestamp" and "&random". An example of a string can be seen below:

TimeStamp:02/Mar/2018:11:46:09 +0100|Request:GET /track/video.mp4%20play/?id=10988&random

I have tried the following:

`grep -Po 'Timestamp \K.*(?= random)'  video.log > outfile.txt`

and:

`sed -n '/Timestamp/,/random/p' video.log > outfile.txt`

I have also tried other things but none of it works.

Comment: Try `TimeStamp:\K.*?(?=&random)`

Comment: I tried: ```grep -Po TimeStamp:\K.*?(?=&random) video.log > outfile.txt```. Which gave me the following error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Your `grep` on Mac does not support `-P` option. You may consider using something like `pcregrep`. Note you have a space after `Timestamp` in the pattern and no space in the string there. Same with `random`: there is `&random` in the string and space+`random` in the pattern.

Comment: Did it work? Else try `ggrep` if you have that installed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have tried: ```pcregrep 'TimeStamp:\K.*?(?=&random)' video.log > outfile.txt``` Which gave me the exact same file as the video.log.

Comment: You forget the `-o` option. Pay attention you have TimeStamp in the string, so the same should be in the pattern.

Comment: No need for pcregrep, use `grep -Eo 'TimeStamp:.*&random' file | sed -E 's/^TimeStamp:|&random$//g' > newfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a non greedy match `.*?` to match until the first occurence of `&random`. For TimeStamp the `S` should be uppercase and instead of a space before random you should use the ampersand itself.

I guess you don't want to log the initial colon so you could start the match with `TimeStamp:`

Your command could look like:

```
grep -Po 'TimeStamp:\K.*?(?=&random)'  video.log > outfile.txt
```

Comment: This does create a .txt file, however, it's an empty file. The following message is shown in the Terminal: ```usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]```

Comment: I think the `-P` option does not work with your version. You could install GNU grep for mac and then run the command with `ggrep`

Comment: @Hugovanp You could use pcregrep without the `-P` like `pcregrep -o 'TimeStamp:\K.*?(?=&random)'  video.log > outfile.txt`

Comment: I installed GNU grep and ran it with ```ggrep``` which worked! Thanks a lot!